# Задержка перед запросом (debonce ) на vue-select?

Tags: vue.js

Мои два метода.

```
searchTo(search, load) {
        if (search !== "") {
            load(true);
            this.getRepositories(search, load, this);
        }
    },
    getRepositories: _.debounce((search, load) => {
        let URL = 'web/settlement/popular'
        if (search) {
            let params = new URLSearchParams({
                "name": search
            })
            URL = 'web/settlement?' + params.toString()
        }
        axios.get(URL)
            .then((response) => {
                this.optionCity = response.data.result
            })
            .then(() => {
                //Отримати міста ЗВІДКИ - кудись .
                axios.post('web/trip/search', {
                    from_id: this.selectedCity.place_id
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.$store.commit('haveTickets', response.data.result)
                        load(false);
                    })
                    .catch(() => load(false));
            })
    }, 250)
```

Селект куда вводу данные

<v-select :options="Object.values(optionCity)"
v-model="selectedCity"
label="city"
class="list-cities bg-white"
@search="searchTo"
v-on:input="searchTo">

Comment: Проблема сейчас в том что оно безконечно грузится и не может найти optioonCIty (оно есть в date())

Answer (score 1):

Используйте не стрелочную функцию в `_.debounce`

```
_.debounce(function(search, load) {
   ...
})
```

Comment: кстати, да я так делал, но у меня не было load активный и я переделал и вариант с не стрелочной функцией